# How to add alternative autocomplete to Search component in UIkit v3

Tags: getuikit

UIkit v3 currently does not support autocomplete in the Search component, but it's is on the roadmap. Until it gets implemented has anyone successfully included a third party autocomplete to the Search component?

I tried to use [jQuery UI autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) which works fine technically, but it does not fit well into UIkit's UI components -- the drop down with suggestions does not render well.

Unfortunately, I'm not profound enough in JavaScript or UIkit to solve this by myself.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest the [JQuery Typeahead Plugin](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) for all things search related? Here is the [Playground](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) for you to give it a go.

Even though JQuery has these plugins you find on their website, the ones you find created by people online are almost always more polished.